# Splitting edges after Mesh Boolean

Tags: geometry-nodes

Mesh Boolean merges all vertices. What I want to do is split the edges the same way they were before the node.

Mesh Island should help, I believe. But if I connect it to the selection input it will affect every face, which is expected.

[image]

[image]

Can I somehow limit the selection to the outer edges of the islands?

[image]

### EDIT

I just used Edge Neighbors equal to 1 and it works with other nodes. But when I use it after Mesh Boolean its data is ignored. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Mesh Boolean` changes the topology of the mesh and merges the points, and thus the edges also lose the previously assigned attributes, you would have to go a different way.

Since the information about which edges were connected to how many faces is no longer directly available in the geometry, you would have to transfer it from the original mesh using `Sample Nearest` and `Sample Index`:

[image]

**Note:** The technique used here with `Sample Nearest` and `Sample Index` (version 3.4+), was solved in earlier versions with `Transfer Attribute`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>